# Navigate to URL and grab href attribute from anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, automation

I have a list of let's say... 10000 URLs. The markup is structured identically but the attributes for some of the DOM elements are unique to the URL.

Is there a was to use JavaScript to:

- Navigate to a URL?
- Grab a DOM element (in my case, pull the href attr for a specific anchor tag)?

Just looking for a push in the right direction. If something like this exists, I am planning to code a loop to iterate through all 10000 URLs and `DoSomething()` with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! I was able to get there using the `WebClient` class and the `IHTMLDocument2` interface in a C# console application.

[WebClient Class Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

[IHTMLDocument2 Interface Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Node.js: look into a Node module like [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), to scrape your URLs and look at their DOM elements. Should be a relatively simple script.